# VBA: Transpose filtered named ranges to another named range

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to loop through named ranges and transpose filtered data based on other named ranges but nothing is happening. I've tried to find --> index but the transpose/filter seems most straightforward. This is what I've been fighting with so far:
Example data:

| criteria | value_to_get |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |

```
For i = 1 to num_unique_criteria 
       crit = Range("criterion_"& i).value
       With WorksheetFunction
            Range("criterion_" & i & "input")(1, 1) = .Transpose.Filter(Range("value_to_get"),Range("criteria") = crit)
       End With
Next i
```

When I print crit value in the (1,1), the correct string prints so it's not that. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

An example output of the above table is :

## A

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

Where the cell with "A" in it = Range("criterion_1") and the row below that are Range("criterion_1_input") in named ranges.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "transpose filter" but you can describe what your code is trying to accomplish, I'll bet I can help.  you are referencing ranges named "criterion_1", "criterion_2", etc. It would be helpful to se what those are as well.  Perhaps you could show a "before" image and a "desired after" image

Comment: I've just added the desired output. Essentially trying to index-match named ranges and get every value in value_to_get based on all row matches in criteria.

Answer (score 0):

There's no WorksheetFunction named `Transpose.Filter()`, you'll
have to apply `Transpose` and `Filter` subsequently:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet ' (Fully) qualify Range reference
Set ws = Sheet1     ' << change to Project's Sheet Code(Name)
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 to num_unique_criteria 
    crit = ws.Range("criterion_"& i).value

    With WorksheetFunction
        ws.Range("criterion_" & i & "input")(1, 1) = .Transpose(.Filter(ws.Range("value_to_get"),ws.Range("criteria") = crit)
    End With
Next i
```

**Note** that you'd do the same in a tabular formula entry by including `Filter(..)` as subordinated argument into the `Transpose(..)` function (i.e. within the outer brackets) like e.g.

```
    =TRANSPOSE(FILTER(valuetoget, criteria=criterion1))
```

*Further hint* Fully qualify your range references, as without explicit reference VBA assumes the currently active sheet which needn't be the one you have in mind. - *If you don't use the VBProject's sheet Code(Name) like in above's example code, you might reference also the tabular worksheet name, like e.g. `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetXY")`.*